# Cleanup erb files by abstracting/moving ruby code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was wondering if it would be possible to cleanup or reorganize my views so that I have less Ruby code. The HTML often becomes cumbersome to work with because it has so much Ruby code.

I thought about moving all the Ruby stuff into helpers and assign each function (links, tags etc.) to methods.

Example. Problem becomes much worse with a more complicated layout.

```
<div class="sidebar">
  <div id="art_nav">
    <%= link_to "Previous", art_path(@previous), :remote => true, :class => "prev" unless @previous.nil? %> 
    <%= link_to "Next", art_path(@next), :remote => true, :class => "next" unless @next.nil? %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Would become:

```
<div class="sidebar">
  <div id="art_nav">
    <%= link_to_previous %>    
    <%= link_to_next %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Helper:

```
def link_to_previous
  link_to "Previous", art_path(@previous), :remote => true, :class => "prev" unless @previous.nil?
end

def link_to_next
  link_to "Next", art_path(@next), :remote => true, :class => "next" unless @next.nil?
end
```

This seems to work with simple examples.. but I am wondering how I should organize stuff when I have to do loops or similar.

**UPDATED: Loop example added**

```
<% arts.each do |art| %>
        <h3><%= art_title %></h3>
        <p><%= art_description %></p>
        <div id="comments_<%= art.id %>">
            <%= render :partial => "/comments/index", :locals => {:resource => art} %>
        </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

What would you do?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "loops or similar". I can't see the question here yet.

Comment: @noodl, I have added an example.

Comment: Could you please be more specific about what you see as the problem with the examples? What is it that you ask? What would an acceptable answer contain? I've voted to close your question as "not a real question" because I find it hard to understand what you're after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a pattern you could use in your code, to clean it up further:

```
def menu(*options, &block)
    params = options[0]
    active = (params[:active] if params) || false
    first = (params[:first] if params) || false
    "
    <div class=\"menu\">
        <div class=\"menu-left #{active ? "active" : "inactive"} #{first ? "first" : "not-first"}\">
        </div>
        <div class=\"menu-center\">
            <div class=\"menu-content #{active ? "active" : "inactive"}\">
              #{capture(&block)}
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class=\"menu-right #{active ? "active" : "inactive"}\">
        </div>
    </div>
    ".html_safe
  end
```

With this helper, code gets very simple:

```
<%= menu(:active => @active_menu == :menu1 ? true : false, :first => true) do %>
    <%= link_to "Les produits et les prix", menu1_path %>
<% end %>
```

At the center of this pattern, there is the call

```
#{capture(&block)}
```

Sorry this example is not "generic" at all, I did a copy-and-paste from my own code. But I'm sure you get the idea.

Comment: This: `@active_menu == :menu1 ? true : false` doesn't need to be a tertiary operation. `@active_menu == :menu1` is exactly equivalent because :== always evaluates to a boolean.

Comment: Also (hope you don't mind my criticising your ruby) you can avoid all that `\"` stuff by using [heredoc](http://www.zenspider.com/Languages/Ruby/QuickRef.html#9) syntax for your big-chunk-o-html.

Comment: @plang, thanks for the example. I am going to create a method for each block of code I move to my helpers. Always end up banging my head against the wall because I try to reuse methods for multiple functions. It just don't work for me - but it makes good sense though :/

Comment: This is so ugly. It's like turning the ERB inside out, strings in Ruby code instead of Ruby code in text. Plus all the escaping (try using  `%Q{...}` or heredocs instead of the quotes around the multiline string). Whatever I'd do, I wouldn't move HTML down into Ruby.

Comment: @Theo How would you abstract a complicated div structure, containing random code then? Thanks for tips, I'm happy I'm learning things everyday.

Comment: It looks like a partial to me... pass in the menu items as a hash (title is the key, the URL the value, or the other way around). To be fair, I don't really understand what the OP is asking for.

Comment: @Theo I was trying to make my views contain only HTML and as little Ruby code is possible. I find it difficult to work with the HTML structure and make changes when there is to much <% ... %> tags etc.